# c++ Binary Search on dates sorted -> i need a range (cca)

Tags: c++, qt, binary-search

I have a binary search on a file. The file is filled with log messages where each line begins with a date (dates or sorted based on event occurs)

example:

- 2011-09-18 09.38.20.123
- 2011-09-18 09.38.20.245
- 2011-09-18 09.38.20.393
- 2011-09-18 09.38.20.400
- 2011-09-18 09.38.20.785

If i need to find this date for example: 2011-09-18 09.38.20.390 my binary search will not find an exact match - but i don't need exact match, i need to find the closest date to it (there is my position).

The current code will jump between 2011-09-18 09.38.20.245 and 2011-09-18 09.38.20.393.

I need some help how to modify the below code so that i get the closest number. In the above situation i would like to have: 2011-09-18 09.38.20.245 (better more than less)

```
BinarySearch::BinarySearch(QString strFileName,QDateTime dtFrom_target,QDateTime dtTo_target)
{

    QFile file(strFileName);
    qint64 nFileSize = file.size();

    int nNewFromPos;
    int nNewToPos;

    nNewFromPos = Search(file, dtFrom_target, nFileSize);
    nNewToPos  = Search(file, dtFrom_target, nFileSize);

    if(nNewFromPos!=-1 && nNewToPos!=-1){
        // now parse the new range

    }
    else{
        // dates out of bound

    }   
}

int BinarySearch::Search(QFile &file, QDateTime dtKey, int nMax) 
{  
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    char lineBuffer[1024];  
    qint64 lineLength;
    QDateTime dtMid;        
    int mid;
    int min; 
    if(!min) min = 0;


   while (min <= nMax) 
   {
       mid=(min+nMax)/2;    // compute mid point.                               
       file.seek(mid);  // seek to middle of file (position based on bytes)
       qint64 lineLength=file.readLine(lineBuffer,sizeof(lineBuffer)); // read until \n or error

       if (lineLength != -1) //something is read
       {
           // validate string begin (pos = 0) starts with date

           lineLength = file.readLine(lineBuffer, 24); //read exactly enough chars for the date from the beginning of the log file


           if(lineLength == 23)
           {
            dtMid = QDateTime::fromString(QString(lineBuffer),"yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss.zzz"); //2011-09-15 09.38.20.192

                if(dtMid.isValid())
                {
                    if(dtKey > dtMid){
                        min = mid + 1; 
                    }
                    else if(dtKey < dtMid){
                        max = mid - 1; // repeat search in bottom half.
                    }
                    else{
                        return mid;     // found it. return position
                    }
                }
            }
       }
   }
   return -1;    // failed to find key
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. If `mid` doesn't happen to coincide with the start of a line, how can this possibly work?

Comment: hi, readLine function reads until \n, after that i read just enough chars from the beginning of the line so that timestamp i have in lineBuffer. From there i just convert to dateTime object and use >,<,= operators for comparing dateTime objects. But the real problem is that i don't need a classic binary search like for example mine above -> i need to find the closest match (exact match will never be found)

Comment: OK, I see how it works now. But you're still doing a byte-based binary search, so after you've found the closest record, you are going to continue searching unnecessarily *within* that record (or the previous record) for its exact byte offset, aren't you?

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure what you mean with "unnecessarily" and "exact byte offset" but the idea is this:

Comment: In my logViewer application, when a user does File->Open he gets the option to use DateFrom & Date To (focus on time interval that interests the user) or he can parse the whole file. I do 2 binary searches for finding the closest or equal (hardly) match in the log file for the user selected DateFrom and DateTo. After that i have narrowed my scope, i would just pass those positions to my main parsing method, wich should then parse the file starting and ending with our new positions. So binary search only narrowed my linear parsing - wich takes about a minute for cca 130mb file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to implement an algorithm equivalent to [`std::equal_range`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal_range/) which returns a pair of result of [`std::lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) and [`std::upper_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/)

1. Find the position of the first element in the sorted range which does not compare less than the value (lower bound)
2. Find the position of the first element in the sorted range which compares greater than  the value (upper bound)

--

```
template<typename OutIter>
void ReadLogsInRange(
    std::istream& logStream, Log::Date from, Log::Date to, OutIter out)
{
    Log l = LowerBound(logStream, from);
    *out++ = l;
    while(logStream >> l && l.date < to)
        *out++ = l;
}
```

Full example: http://ideone.com/CvIYm